# How to match nodes and their relationships with the main node?

Tags: neo4j, match, relationship

I have a graph like this:

```
({id: 1, name: 'Winston'}) --[{name: 'Bill'}]--> ({id: 2, name: 'Max'})

                        ({id: 3, name: 'Steve'})
```

I want to match nodes with id = 2 or 3 and replace property name in them by name from relationship with node which has id = 1:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Bill"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Steve"
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to execute this: MATCH (u), ({id: 1})-[r]->(u) WHERE u.id IN [2, 3] RETURN u, r. It returns only node with id = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you should be using labels on your nodes. For example's sake let's use :Person. As your graph gets larger you should also be adding indexes on the labels/properties used for node lookup.

For this case, only adding/replacing the name property of nodes based on a relationship property when connected to a starting node with id:1, we can do the following:

```
MATCH (:Person {id: 1})-[r]->(u:Person)
SET u.name = r.name
```